# Почему telegram бот не отвечает на сообщения в группе которые не адрессованы ему?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Почему бот не отвечает на сообещние которое не адрессовано ему в группе, а лишь в переписку с ним.
[image: Вот такая проблема]

Тут код - https://pastebin.com/jkmcz23V

Comment: потому что верблюд в пустыне плюнул, код где?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jkmcz23V

Comment: проверил ваш код, всё работает.
для отладки можете использовать

# Отладка
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)